# knockout js data binding is working on parent screen but not working in popup window on a asp.net / vb.net web app

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, knockout.js, asp.net-ajax

I am developing a web application built with asp.net and vb.net

I have a page (update_status.aspx) which is using knockout js to display a datepicker depending upon the value selected by the user on select box. the code is like below.

```
 <%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="E4.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="update-status.aspx.vb" Inherits="E4_Jobs_Details_Application_update_status" %>


 <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="Server">

       <div class="entry-wrapper">
            <input type="hidden" id="appId" value="<%= VacancyApplication.ID%>" />

            <div class="form-element">
                <label>Current status</label>
                <input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="<%= VacancyApplication.Status%>" />
            </div>

            <div class="form-element">
                <label>New status (required)</label>
                <select id="comNewStatus" runat="server" datavaluefield="id" datatextfield="name" class="nFee"></select>
            </div>
            <div data-bind="visible: statusId() == 12">
                <label>
                    Start date (required, format: DD-MMM-YYYY)
                </label>
                <div class="input-append">
                    <span class="add-on "><span class="icon-calendar"></span></span>
                    <input class="dp" size="16" type="text" value="" runat="server" id="txtStartDate" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </asp:Content>
```

The problem is this data-binding doesnot work when i convert this page as popup page by changing its master page (like below). that is the calender doesnot come up when user selects the right status.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="E4_Popup.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="update-status.aspx.vb" Inherits="E4_Jobs_Details_Application_update_status" %>
```

Both E4.master and E4_Popup.master is using the same style and same code file .

```
<%@ Master Language="VB" CodeFile="E4.master.vb" Inherits="_resx_E4" %>
```

the only difference is they are different files and E4_Popup.master doesnot contains the extra bits of the web page (e.g; headers and footers ).

But even if I copy E4.master page as E4_Popup.master page and refer it to the update status page .. the calender does not come up. It just not working on the pages other than E4.master page.

I dont understand what the problem is..

What shall I do? Please help me with right advice.

Please see the knockout apply bindings code below

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ScriptContent" runat="Server">
<script type="text/javascript">

    var ViewModel = function () {
        var self = this;
        self.histories = ko.observableArray([]);
        self.statusId = ko.observable(0);
        self.feeType = ko.observable(0);
        self.agencyApp = ko.observable(false);
        self.offeredSalary = ko.observable(0);
        self.finalSalary = ko.observable(0);
        self.introductionFee = ko.observable(0);

    };
    var vm = new ViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(vm);

    $(function () {
        $("select.chosen").chosen();
        dimNav('vacancy');




        var aid = $('#appId').val(), feeType = $('#feeType').val(), agencyApp = $('#agencyApp').val();
        vm.feeType(parseInt(feeType));
        vm.agencyApp(agencyApp);

        $('.nFee').change(function () {
            vm.statusId(parseInt($(this).val()));
        });


        //numeric only
        $('.txtOfferedSalary, .txtFinalIntroductionFee,.txtFinalSalary').keydown( function(event) {
            // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, and enter
            if (event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9 || event.keyCode == 27 || event.keyCode == 13 ||
                // Allow: Ctrl+A
                (event.keyCode == 65 && event.ctrlKey === true) ||
                // Allow: home, end, left, right
                (event.keyCode >= 35 && event.keyCode <= 39)) {
                // let it happen, don't do anything
                return;
            } else {
                // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
                if (event.shiftKey || (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) && (event.keyCode < 96 || event.keyCode > 105)) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            }
        });



        $.when(
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/_services/UtilityService.asmx/applicationstatushistories",
                data: "{id:" + aid + "}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                cache: true
            })).done(function (r) {
                vm.histories($.parseJSON(r.d));
                //console.log();
                momentize();
            });
    });
  </script>
 </asp:Content>
```

When I run the application ... for the E4.master page,E4_popup.master page and update_status_popup.aspx page the following type of warning comes up

**Namespace or type specified in the Imports 'Telerik.WebControls' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found. Make sure the namespace or the type is defined and contains at least one public member. Make sure the imported element name doesn't use any aliases.**

If you need more information please let me know

Comment: There must be extra code around your example that you haven't shown.  For instance, where is `ko.applyBindings` being called etc.

Comment: Hi I have edite my question. please see my question to see the code. just to make clear if i just change the master file name in the page from e4.master to e4_popup.master ... the datepicker doesnot come up. even if the both master pages are exactly same  with different names.

Comment: When I run the application ... for the update_status_popup.aspx page the following type of warning comes up  Warning 108 Validation (XHTML 1.0 Transitional): Attribute 'data-bind' is not a valid attribute of element 'div'. update-status_popup.aspx